# What is returned when a Rust FFI function returns a struct without #[repr(C)] to C?

Tags: rust, ffi

EDIT: It was pointed out that my example isn't complete enough to be useful. My question is resolved, but if you're interested in looking at the complete code you can see it [here](https://github.com/anderspitman/messtcp/blob/ea27eef487117b8df9e006a808f80b6169edea01/src/lib.rs).

Given the following code:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn create_acceptor() -> Acceptor {
    Acceptor {}
}

pub struct Acceptor {}
```

If I call this from C what does it actually get? Is it a pointer? An id of some sort?

I'm currently using code like the following on the C side:

```c
extern int create_acceptor();

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        int acceptor = create_acceptor();
        return 0;
}
```

It seems to work fine. I'm using it like an opaque type that I pass back to Rust like `acceptor_doSomething(acceptor)`.

But I'm confused because it doesn't seem to matter what type I use for `acceptor` on the C side. `void*` and `int` both behave the same. Also, the documentation seems to indicate that I should be using `#[repr(C)]`, but it seems to work without it. Why is that?

When printing the value received on the C side, it's showing very small integers, so I'm guessing it's an id on the Rust side?

Comment: empty type is not a thing in C, Also return an empty type don't make much sense to me, however `void` should "work" in most case. But `int` don't make any sense, rust empty type are empty.

Comment: Yeah sorry it's not a great example. I edited in a link to my actual code. Anyway my question has been answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: The example isn't a useful one and doesn't show anything.

> what does it actually get? Is it a pointer? An id of some sort?

It's the struct, exactly as defined on the Rust side. It's a pointer if you return a pointer (this example does not) or an id if you return some id (this example does not).

Rust's FFI imposes no overhead or abstraction — what you return is what is returned.

> the documentation seems to indicate that I should be using `#[repr(C)]`

Yes, *you should*. Without it, your code is most likely undefined behavior. The layout of a Rust struct is not yet guaranteed. Without specifying the representation as C, there's no way for the C code to know which fields are where.

> but it seems to work without it

That's because your example struct has no fields and thus no size (which AFAIK isn't even valid in C without non-standard extensions). Rust basically never even needs to look at the data (what data?) so it doesn't matter what you pass back.

> When printing the value received on the C side, it's showing very small integers

This is probably just junk on the stack laying around. Literally uninitialized data.

## Using a struct with fields without `#[repr(C)]`

This is **bad**. Don't do it. `String` is a struct with non-trivial fields and it is not marked `#[repr(C)]`.

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "shear"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["An Devloper"]

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
```

**src/lib.rs**

```
// Don't do this, `String` isn't #[repr(C)]!
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn create_example() -> String {
    String::from("hello")
}

// Don't do this, `String` isn't #[repr(C)]!
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn use_example(e: String) {
    println!("{}", e);
}
```

**main.c**

```c
extern int create_example();
extern void use_example(int example);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int example = create_example();
  use_example(example);
}
```

**Execution**

```
$ cargo build
   Compiling shear v0.1.0 (file:///home/ubuntu/shear)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.02s
$ gcc -o example main.c -L target/debug/ -lshear
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=target/debug/ ./example
Segmentation fault
```

---

Please read the [The Rust FFI Omnibus](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/) for details about how to properly transfer values across the FFI boundary. Disclaimer: I am the primary author.

Comment: Yeah I dumbed down the example to cut down on the noise. Apparently I cut too much. In my actual code I'm storing nontrivial data (TcpListener and TcpStream) and after passing them to C and back I'm able to successfully send and receive data on the sockets.

Comment: @anderspitman you put a struct containing those as an `int` on the C half of the code? They definitely cannot fit in that. I bet if you run in valgrind you will get a whole mess of errors.

Comment: Haha yeah. I was very surprised it was working at all. I'll read the omnibus and report back when I have a better overall understanding.

Comment: The omnibus is an excellent resource, and makes it obvious what I was doing wrong. In any case your answer makes it clear what I was doing is wrong and likely undefined, which is the correct answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: just wanted to report back and say thanks again. I was able to get everything working using the Omnibus as a guide.